# How to change audio control volume in sencha touch 2

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, html5-audio

I added audio control on panel. I'm just settings its url and nothing else. 
On running the app I can see the audio control and song is also played. I can do actions like play/pause/mute volume. Hovering on volume control i get volume changer seek bar but I am not able to change the volume. I am using chrome to test my application.

Any idea on how to handle volume change of audio control ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the volume programmatically,
you can use the 'setVolume' method on your 'audio' xtype element:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Audio-method-setVolume
You just pass a float value between 0.0 (minimum) and 1.0 (maximum).

If you are talking about the automatic control panel, look at this fiddle:
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#fOAGD#CcDKl
I am testing this one in Chrome and I am perfectly able to change the volume using the native slider. I also added a custom slider to show you how you can do it programmatically.

Can you precise what your problem is?

Comment: Actually, there's no point in setting the `volume` as it can be set from range of `0.0` to `1.0`. Default value is `1`. So, you can't increase the `volume`. So, it's more like a boolean value .. 0 (no volume) or 1(max volume) .... http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Media-cfg-volume

Comment: @roadRunner I don't get your point. It's a float value between 0.0 and 1.0. By default, it is set to its maximum (1.0) but you can change the volume to any value (like 0.5 for instance).

Comment: Sorry, I missed one point there. Yes, you can set volume for 0.5 for instance, but I don't think, anything of that range would make any difference.

Comment: @roadRunner Yes it does, please have a look at the fiddle I propose in my answer. The range is between 0.0 and 1.0, any float value in that range is valid (setting the volume between and 0% and 100% if you prefer).

Comment: @roadRunner I'm sorry, it works in Chrome but doesn't work on my iPhone. I will investigate this. Probably related to the volume control of the device itself...

Comment: .I also doubt, whether it will work on Android, since SenchaTouch doesn't support media elements well on Android platforms,

Comment: I checked you fiddle in that you are able to use native control. Well even i have similar markup i am not able to use native control.